# Executing sencha minify command from build.xml

Tags: build, build-process, sencha-cmd

I'm trying to minify an additional file that is not included in the whole build process after the build finished.
I think this could be done from within the build.xml file by calling the sencha cmd from the "-after-build" section and tried the following way:

```
<target name="-after-build">
    <x-sencha-command dir="${build.dir}">
        fs
            minify
                -f additional-file.js
                -t additional-file.min.js
                -yui
    </x-sencha-command>
</target>
```

Unfortunately this results in an pretty generic error:

```
[INF] -after-build:
[ERR]
[ERR] BUILD FAILED
[ERR] com.sencha.exceptions.BasicException
[ERR]
[ERR] Total time: 18 seconds
[ERR] The following error occurred while executing this line:
...\build.xml:31: com.sencha.exceptions.BasicException
```

Line 31 of build.xml is:

```
<x-sencha-command dir="${build.dir}">
```

How can this be done?

Thanks & best regards

ps.: I've already posted this question on the sencha forum but didn't get no repsonse so far: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?272190-Executing-sencha-minify-command-from-build.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above task-call was only missing "=" between the parameternames (-t & -f) and their values. So this is working:

```
<x-sencha-command>
    fs
        minify
            -f=${build.dir}/bootstrap-app.js
            -t=${build.dir}/bootstrap-app.js
            ${build.compression}
</x-sencha-command>
```